# BG images rendering problem in IE

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

I have multiple background images **(all of my images are either in jpg or gif format)** in my website and it renders smoothly in firefox, **but some of those images doesn't render in IE** and when I scroll through the page some of the images renders and then disappears again. This implies with css sprites too.

Answer (score 0):

Do the HTML and CSS code validate?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a caching issue perhaps? Does the image render well if you refresh the page?
If so, add meta no-cache refresh tags to your  section.

It could be I'm barking up the wrong tree, but i had plenty of caching problems with IE.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the Peek-a-boo bug.

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html